# Change all a hrefs with javascript?

Tags: javascript, href

How could I change all hrefs with custom URL on page load?

Sorry, I just have no clue how I could do that. Don't realy know any js.

Thanks to anyone who can help me. Realy appreciate it.

Comment: If you don't know anything, and you obviously didn't read [ask], kindly do read it. Also, delete this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
// Execute this when the document is ready.
window.onload = function () {
  // Get all the `<a>` tags.
  var all_a = document.querySelectorAll("a");
  // Loop through all the `<a>` tags.
  for (i = 0; i < all_a.length; i++)
    // Change the `href`:
    all_a[i].setAttribute("href", "whatever_you_want");
}
```